# TRANSLATE not working inside XMLAGG

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I want to use `TRANSLATE` to replace invalid XML characters in a string that's used in `XMLAGG` instead of nested `REPLACE` due to the large number of characters that need to be replaced:

```
select c.key,  
  cast( substr( xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ' | ', 
    replace(replace(replace(replace(c.comment_text,chr(160),' '), chr(191),' '), chr(176),' '), chr(190),' ')
    --translate(c.comment_text, ' ', chr(160)||chr(176)||chr(190)||chr(191))
   ) ) order by c.comment_date desc ) as clob ), 3, 4000 ) as varchar2) as sum_comment
from comments c  
where c.comment_date > current_timestamp - 90
group by c.key
```

If I run this outside of the `XMLAGG` I can see that both the `TRANSLATE` and `REPLACE` are removing the invalid characters, but inside the `XMLAGG` I get the error I'm trying to avoid when using `TRANSLATE`:

```
An illegal XML character "#xA0" was found in an SQL/XML expression or function argument that begins with string " | A".
```

Comment: What version and platform of DB2? I suggest you double-check that the stand-alone `TRANSLATE()` does indeed work as you think it does.

Comment: I would verify that `comment_text` might already contain HTML entity. These would expand to `&amp;#xA0;` when you're looking for `&#xA0;`